# How to make compatible existing app to iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iphone-x

We have an application with 6 to 8 screens which was developed by Swift 3.2 version. And I am using Size classes (Auto Resize),not using autolayouts for all devices its working fine.

But, Now, We want to make it compatible with iPhone X device.

While we testing app in iPhone X, there are lot of issues on top, bottom views and even centre of the screen in Subviews.

I have seen, few forums which were told, "Use adaptive Sage Guide" in Story board files of UI, and issue would be solved. But, Event I tried that, still lot of gaps and issues coming bottom and top while testing app with iPhone X.

So, how to make compatible with iPhone X with my existing code, do I need to change everything in programmatically for `below iPhone X and iPhone X,` or is there anything there?

Can anyone suggest me, how to proceed for this.

Note : We are using Xcode 9.2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using `Safe Area Layout Guides`

Comment: As per some forums said, I tried that, but, nothing helped me.

Comment: Assuming a few typos - virtually *everything* for "seamless" iPhoneX *requires* (a) auto layout - which you aren't using? - *and* (b) "safe areas". Unfortunately for you, it seems you aren't using both. If you are *not using autolayouts"* you likely have a lot of work to do. So to finish, I'd suggest you (1) use auto layout for all your screens and then (2) use the "safe area". There *is* code for this - but it assumes auto layout. Finally, I may be misunderstanding - I always thought size classes should mean layout constraints, not frames.

Comment: can you please share the pic what kind of iphone X issuse you are facing

Comment: Updated query, please check.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just an iPhone X thing, it's also an iOS 11 thing. iOS 11 introduces a brand new inset adjustment API that deprecates most (maybe all?) of what preceded it. And with iPhone X's physical design, even more attention to safe areas must be made.

So get used to writing these:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

    // new iOS 11 syntax
    someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true

} else {

    // pre-iOS 11 syntax
    someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` is now a property of the view itself and it's more intuitive, IMO. More examples of the new API syntax:

```
someView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
someView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
someView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

And if you're interested in getting inset values:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    someViewAnchor.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
} else {
    someViewAnchor.constant = bottomLayoutGuide.length
}
```

> If you’re using storyboards, you should open them now, go the file
>   inspector, then select the Use Safe Area Layout guide checkbox – that
>   will switch you over to the new system.
>   https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/12/how-to-update-your-app-design-for-iphone-x

Comment: Even middle of the subviews getting more space in iPhone X compare with other iPhone devices.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by middle of the view getting more space?

Comment: I can't share here screenshot due to privacy

Comment: But, in subview some space is getting more in centre screen iPhone X device. @Mia

Comment: waiting for your response @Mia

Comment: can u respond here?

Answer (score 0):

After adding `Safe Area Guides` you need to do little changes in constraints attribute like those constraints which are using superview.top and superview.bottom of the screen after applying the `Safe Guide` the `superview` need to change to the `Safe Area` like in the picture below

[image]

Comment: But, We are not using auto-layout except single screen. Then, how this will work?